# Why electrons and protons accepted as sub atomic particles?

Tags: particle-physics, electricity

Why and how electrons and protons accepted as sub atomic particles during evacuated tubes experiment. I mean they could be something bigger than atoms or could be other than atoms or could be atoms

Edit:
Ok as suggested on comment here is the experiment about which I am taking about
[image]

Comment: For electrons, see [Determination of electron mass in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mass#Determination). The proton history is [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton#History). Note that they both carry an electric charge, so they cannot be atoms (which are neutral - although a proton can be viewed as a hydrogen ion or as the nucleus of a hydrogen atom) .

Comment: Electrons and protons are, by definition, sub-atomic particles because they are constituents of atoms. As to their role in the "evacuated tubes experiment", you will have to give more details about the experiment that you have in mind before that can be answered.

Answer (score 6):

This belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

You must have learned in school that in 1897  J J Thompson, through deflection in electric and magnetic fields, could estimate the mass of the cathode ray particle to be 1/1836 the mass of the hydrogen ion,  hence the smallest atom's.

*Therefore* it had to be something much  lighter than an atom.

The assignation of elementarity to a particle is ever only tentative,  predicated on failure to observe substructure in it. After all, the proton (above) was understood to be composite in [1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering).

Comment: Minor objection: the equivalence between “much less massive” and “much smaller” is based on macroscopic intuition where most “stuff” has roughly the same density. There’s a reasonable argument (which doesn’t really fit in a comment) that a better “size” for an electron is its wavelength, in which case a free, cold electron might be “larger” than an electron whose wavefunction fills the atom to which it is confined.

Comment: @rob Indisputably; but at the time, 19th century, people had no idea of the UP...